# Convert IBM JMSMessageId to String in JAVA

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am receiving following sting in properties from IBM MQ as message Id, I want to convert it back to original value in string or integer. Please help me do that.

```
JMSMessageID=ID:c1d4d840d8e4c16dd4d8404040404040520b91682005a90d
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information. What does the 'original value' mean? What would it be in your example?

Answer (score 2):

What you see after `JMSMessageID=ID` i.e. `c1d4d840d8e4c16dd4d8404040404040520b91682005a90d` is the real (or original) message id. It is 24 byte long. You can't convert that into an integer.